# Solving for a variable in terms of others.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is about solving $\alpha$ in terms of $\beta$, $z$ and $c$ in the equation: $$\frac{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}{z}=\frac{\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta}}{c}$$

To be fair, this question was given to me from a friend who he had made this up on a whim. So I don't know if it's possible or not to solve for $\alpha$ in such a equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply throught by $z$ & $c$ & use the sin addition formula $ \sin( \alpha +  \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta+ \cos \alpha \sin \beta$ ... Then collect all the $\alpha$ together
\begin{eqnarray*}
c \sin \alpha \cos \beta+ c \cos \alpha \sin \beta = z \sin \alpha + z \sin \beta \\
(c  \cos \beta -z) \sin \alpha+ c \cos \alpha \sin \beta =   z \sin \beta 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assume the LHS has the form $R \sin (\alpha + \phi)= R \sin \alpha \cos \phi +\cos \alpha \sin \phi$ ... we have the following simultaneous equations ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
R \cos \phi =c \cos \beta -z \\
R \sin \phi = c \sin \beta
\end{eqnarray*}
...
Square each of these equations & add, to get $R$ and divide the equations to get $ \tan \phi $
\begin{eqnarray*}
R^2  =c^2 -2cz \cos \beta +z^2 \\
\tan \phi = \frac{c \sin \beta}{c \cos \beta -z}
\end{eqnarray*}
So the solution is $R \sin( \alpha + \phi) = z \sin \beta$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{z \sin \beta}{ \sqrt{c^2 -2cz \cos \beta +z^2}} \right) - \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{c \sin \beta}{c \cos \beta -z} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What made you conclude that R is positve?

Comment: Is it because R^2 resembles the law of cosine of a triangle with sides, R, c and z?

Comment: $ \cos \beta \le 1 $ so $c^2 -2cz \cos \beta +z^2 \ge c^2 -2cz  +z^2 =(z-c)^2 \ge 0 $

Comment: That's quite clever! I didn't see that.